# Use both AddForceAtPoint and change velocity property?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm using Rigidbody2D for some game objects. It seems that when I `AddForce()` or `AddForceAtPoint()`, the game objects are mostly affected on the Y axis and hardly at all on the x axis. I don't understand why. To really get any effect on the x axis, I need to have a very strong force like *10 000. But the effect on the y axis is then extremely strong and shoots the object out of screen, yet only nudges the game object on the x scale.

I believe that the problem with the y axis is because I use `.velocity` to move the character. But I don't know how to change the velocity directly without doing that.  What should I do to use both forces and set velocity on the same object?

Comment: We would need to see your implementation of `ZombieBoyController.AddForceAtPosition()` to have the full story.

Comment: [You might find this answer helpful](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113178/when-should-i-use-velocity-versus-addforce-when-dealing-with-player-objects/113203#113203) - it discusses the pitfalls of setting velocity directly, since that tends to override any other physics influences on the object. You'll likely want to move your character with forces & accelerations if you want them to react to outside forces correctly.

Comment: Your problem with the "required" high forces is, that you aren't applying them "over a distance" - meaning, you aren't actually doing "work" on the object. I'll just suggest to look up the words "Force", "Work" and "Kinetic Energy" in Wikipedia! But here some formula you will need: F = m*a; W = F*d; and E = 0.5*m*v^2

Comment: can you share a code or inspector?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the AddForceAtPosition, which will apply a force to a particular position on the rigid body.  You are entering the direction vector on the zombie rigidbody as a position. You should just use the following:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce (direction.normalized * force);
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the y axis wether i use AddForce or AtPosition. But it is the AtPosition that i want to use. 

I just realized that the problem with the y axis is because i use .velocity to move the character. But i dont know how to do it without changing the velocity.

Comment: Why do you want to use AtPosition?

Comment: Im using at position because i want a force at one point to affect all objects within distance. Why do you seem to think that this is strange?

Answer (score -1):

AddForceAtPosition is the function of RigidBody, right? It would appear that you're calling it incorrectly; it should be force first, then position.

For more information, [See the API reference for Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html).

Comment: Uhm no, i just switched the places in the wrapping method. I added it to the question. Sorry.